# Split dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I have a dataset like this

```
alpha number  fr color
1     a   20 0.8   rot
2     a   21 2.0   rot
3     a    2 0.8   rot
4     a   34 0.8   rot
5     f   42 0.5  grün .......
......................
```

Now I want to split this dataset in more observations which depends on a condition like number<20 so that the new dataset looks like

```
alpha number  fr color
1     a   19 0.8   rot
2     a   1  0.8   rot
3     a   10 2.0   rot
4     a   11 2.0   rot
5     a    2 0.8   rot
6     a   19 0.8   rot
7     a   15 0.8   rot
8     f   7  0.5  grün 
9     f   7  0.5  grün 
10     f   7  0.5  grün 
11    f   7  0.5  grün 
12     f   7  0.5  grün 
13    f   7  0.5  grün 
 .......
```

Or similarly repeat the observations as long as the condition is not true.

How to split doesn't matter but the observations have to be the same for the data you split for the other variables?

Comment: It's not clear how you come from first chunk to the second one. Can you make your example reproducible and exactly what the expected result should be? Please show what you've tried so far in terms of the algorithm and coding.

Comment: I only want to split the rows in repeating rows if the number is bigger 20. how the rows look like doesnt matter. so you split the first one in two equal rows with 10 as number or you can split them into 3 rows with 8, 9, 3 and so on. but the rest of the variables have to be the same. a has to be a for the row you split for example in two new rows.

Answer (score 0):

```r
df1 <- structure(list(alpha = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "f"), 
                      number = c(20L, 21L, 2L, 34L, 42L), 
                      fr = c(0.8, 2, 0.8, 0.8, 0.5), 
                      color = c("rot", "rot", "rot", "rot", "grun")), 
                 row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

```r
rep.rev <- function(x,t){
  if(t != 0){
    rep(x,t)
  } else {
    NA_integer_
  }
}
```

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
```

```r
set.seed(22)
```

```r
df1 %>% 
  mutate(divisor = floor(runif(n(), min = 2, max = 19)),
         quotient = number%/%divisor,
         remainder = ifelse(number%%divisor==0, NA, number%%divisor)) %>% 
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(number = list(c(rep.rev(divisor, quotient),remainder))) %>% 
  unnest %>% 
  select(alpha, number, fr, color) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(number))
```

```r
#> # A tibble: 14 x 4
#>    alpha number    fr color
#>    <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
#>  1 a          7   0.8 rot  
#>  2 a          7   0.8 rot  
#>  3 a          6   0.8 rot  
#>  4 a         10   2   rot  
#>  5 a         10   2   rot  
#>  6 a          1   2   rot  
#>  7 a          2   0.8 rot  
#>  8 a         10   0.8 rot  
#>  9 a         10   0.8 rot  
#> 10 a         10   0.8 rot  
#> 11 a          4   0.8 rot  
#> 12 f         16   0.5 grun 
#> 13 f         16   0.5 grun 
#> 14 f         10   0.5 grun
```

Answer (score 0):

Many ways we could split a number >=20, but the method below divides the each number in half, i.e. even numbers (m=2n) split into n and n, odd numbers (m=2n+1) split into (n+1) and n.

```
> library(dplyr)
> df <- data.frame(alpha=c("a","a","a","a","f"),
+                  number=c(20,21,2,34,42),
+                  fr=c(0.8,2.0,0.8,0.8,0.5),
+                  color=c("rot","rot","rot","rot","grün"))
```

The function `doSplit()` takes a dataframe `df` and an integer `threshold` as arguments.

```
> doSplit <- function(df, threshold){
+   # splits rows where number >= threshold until all rows have number < threshold
+   
+   colNames <- colnames(df)
+   df <- df %>% mutate(orig_id=rownames(df))
+   dfBelow <- df %>% filter(number<threshold)
+   dfAbove1 <- df %>% filter(number>=threshold) %>% mutate(number=(number%/%2)+(number%%2))
+   dfAbove2 <- df %>% filter(number>=threshold) %>% mutate(number=number%/%2)
+   combData <- rbind(dfBelow, dfAbove1, dfAbove2)
+   combData <- combData %>% arrange(orig_id) %>% select(colNames)
+   return(combData)  
+ }
```

Here, we define a threshold of 20.  The `while` loop repeatedly calls the `doSplit()` function so long as a row exists with number >=20.

```
> myThreshold <- 20
> splitDf <- df
> while(splitDf %>% pull(number) %>% max() >= myThreshold){
+     splitDf <- doSplit(splitDf, myThreshold)
+ }
```

Here is the split dataframe:

```
> splitDf
   alpha number  fr color
1      a     10 0.8   rot
2      a     10 0.8   rot
3      a     11 2.0   rot
4      a     10 2.0   rot
5      a      2 0.8   rot
6      a     17 0.8   rot
7      a     17 0.8   rot
8      f     11 0.5  grün
9      f     10 0.5  grün
10     f     11 0.5  grün
11     f     10 0.5  grün
```